# Why dows exec() function work in raw code but not within a function or a class in Python 3.7?

Tags: exec, python-3.7

Below I show 2 usage examples of exec() function in Python 3.7, one in a class, and one in raw code. Only the latter works properly. Could someone explain to me possible reasons and suggest solutions?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

################################# exec() WITHIN A CLASS ###################################
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def f(self):
        pose, frame, min_complexE, min_lEfree, best_structvar, best_conf, complexE, ligandE_bound, proteinE_bound, \
        min_lEfree = [None] * 10
        table = pd.read_table("sample_scores.txt", delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=[0])  # 1st line is a comment
        table_columns = table.columns
        for i, row in table.iterrows():
            # Variable assignemnt
            for varname in ["pose", "frame", "min_complexE", "min_lEfree", "best_structvar", "best_conf",
                            "complexE", "ligandE_bound", "proteinE_bound", "min_lEfree", "Eint"]:
                if varname in table_columns:
                    exec("%s = %s" % (varname, row[varname]), globals(), globals())
                else:
                    exec("%s = None" % (varname), globals(), globals())

            print("proteinE_bound within class =", proteinE_bound)

    def caller1(self):
        self.f()

    def caller2(self):
        self.caller1()

Test().caller2()

################################# exec() IN RAW CODE ###################################
pose, frame, min_complexE, min_lEfree, best_structvar, best_conf, complexE, ligandE_bound, proteinE_bound, \
min_lEfree = [None] * 10
table = pd.read_table("sample_scores.txt", delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=[0])  # 1st line is a comment
table_columns = table.columns
for i, row in table.iterrows():
    # Variable assignemnt
    for varname in ["pose", "frame", "min_complexE", "min_lEfree", "best_structvar", "best_conf",
                    "complexE", "ligandE_bound", "proteinE_bound", "min_lEfree", "Eint"]:
        if varname in table_columns:
            exec("%s = %s" % (varname, row[varname]), globals(), globals())
        else:
            exec("%s = None" % (varname), globals(), globals())
    print("proteinE_bound as raw code =", proteinE_bound)
```

The contents of the "sample_scores.txt" file are:

```
# Contains all results. For the best result for each compound please refer to file BEST_RESULTS.
molname Eint    complexE    ligandE_bound   proteinE_bound  stereoisomer    ionstate    tautomer    pose    frame
LEM00001847 -63.000496 -17406.593934 -84.868633 -17258.724804 1 1 1 1 571
LEM00001847 -62.412897 -17474.918135 -64.778724 -17347.726515 1 1 1 1 171
LEM00001847 -61.249384 -17423.452346 -82.875735 -17279.327226 1 1 1 1 531
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer although there are still some obscure points in it. Basically, I had to remove the line

```
pose, frame, min_complexE, min_lEfree, best_structvar, best_conf, complexE, ligandE_bound, proteinE_bound, \
        min_lEfree = [None] * 10
```

where I initialized the variables to be assigned by exec(). If these variables do not pre-exist, then they are successfully added to the globals() and are accessible within the function as individual variables.

Now the obscure points:

1) Even if I initialize these 10 variables to None, in every iteration of the for loop their values are updated in globals() dictionary but not when I call then with their names as individual variables.

2) According to docs.python.org `exec(__object, __globals=..., __locals=...)`. It seems that only the given '__globals' dictionary is updated with the new variables. So although in my code above I use

```
exec("%s = %s" % (varname, row[varname]), globals(), globals())
```

this works as well

```
exec("%s = %s" % (varname, row[varname]), locals(), globals())
```

In my understanding, the latter is the right way, because you want these variables to be created within the context of the function, namely as local variables. But then why exec() updates the given '__globals' and not the given '__locals'?